# "Unknown named module" error in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-modules

I'm creating an app using react native but some imports raise the error from the title: `"Unknown named module"`. This happens with two packages, `react-native-material-design` and `react-native-db-models`, so I suspect the problem isn't on the modules but in my setup.

I tried linking the packages with `react-native link` and repackaging the app using `react-native run-android`, but none of these solved this issue. I've looked up examples of imports on github, and even copying working code raises the same error.

I tried installing the modules using either yarn and npm. I tried with relative paths like `../../react-native-db-models`. Didn't work!

This is how I import the modules:

```
import RNDBModel from 'react-native-db-models';

import { List, Button, Toolbar, } from 'react-native-material-design';
```

These are my project dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "15.4.1",
  "react-native": "0.39.2",
  "react-native-db-models": "^0.1.3",
  "react-native-material-design": "^0.3.7",
  "react-native-md-textinput": "^2.0.4",
  "react-native-vector-icons": "0.8.5",
  "react-redux": "^5.0.1",
  "redux": "^3.6.0",
  "redux-logger": "^2.7.4"
},
```

If React/React Native is incompatible with these modules, how do I figure out which version should I use? Maybe the error has nothing to do with imports and has something to do with my project?

Comment: For the react-native-material-design package. I am using it on a different project and is working fine. But for the react-native-db-models. I am not sure. It hasn't been updated for a years. Could you give an output of an example with only the react-native-material-design package ?

Comment: @SaadBen same error: `Unknown named module: "react-native-material-design"`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The package server started by `react-native start` seems to have a cache of the node modules. Stopping and restarting the server solved the issue.

Always restart your react server after installing modules!

Answer (score 1):

A quick check on the package's [repository](https://github.com/react-native-material-design/react-native-material-design/blob/master/lib/index.js) shows 'List' module is no longer available. Here is a [link](https://github.com/react-native-material-design/react-native-material-design/issues/18) to why it was removed.

So, you will have to remove 'List' module from your import:

```
import { Button, Toolbar, } from 'react-native-material-design';
```