# React native not finding modules

Tags: node.js, npm, socket.io, react-native

I have been having a bit of trouble with React Native 0.39.2 finding certain modules after doing a clean `init`.

I installed `socket.io-client` via `npm install socket.io-client --save`

I ran `react-native run-android` and a red screen popped up with:

> Unknown named module: xmlhttprequest-ssl

That nested dependency didn't appear to be installed, so I went ahead and installed it:

`npm install xmlhttprequest-ssl --save`

I definitely see it in the root of my `node_modules` folder, but my android emulator keeps throwing up the error page with `Unknown named module: 'xmlhttprequest-ssl'`

I have tried blowing away `node_modules` and running `npm install` and that didn't work. Neither did `npm clean cache`. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: A clean init shouldn't reference any new modules that are installed. What does your index file look like?

Comment: this is a duplicated question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232861/unknown-named-module-error-in-react-native

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me when i declare
    `import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js'`

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the emulator +  react-packager terminal, after node installs package.

Comment: How does one restart the `react-native-cli`?

Comment: I meant react-packager terminal, it is terminated through ctrl+c